# Cannot Profile a PHP web application hosted on a remote server, Xdebug works

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have a remote server on my local network. I have PHPStorm and XDebug set up there with the following `.ini` settings for my xdebug:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_port=9022

xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/xdbgsnapshots
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

The webserver running XDebug is running on port 88, so I when I connect to debug, I do the following:

1. Set a breakpoint somewhere in my code
2. Turn on `Listen to incoming PHP Debug connections`
3. Connect to the webserver at port 88
4. Debug as needed

I would have thought that this set up was sufficient for profiling as well, but I cannot make it work (i.e. nothing gets saved to the directory). I am using the bookmark triggers [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) to try and trigger the profiling start and end, but it doesn't seem to do anything (possibly because the xdebug is not running on my machine, but on the remote server).

Howe can I set up profiling, given the above configuration? Running it against a local codebase is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 0):

> In order for the trigger to work properly, xdebug.profiler_enable needs to be set to 0.

xdebug.profiler_enable=0

Ref: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler